# HTTP Request 301 Redirect serving different content to HTTPS With No Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Using .htaccess I recently redirected all of my sites http:// requests to https:// using the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The 301 redirect is working and now everyone is landing on https. However, when a user uses a bookmarked link that is http:// or I send them a Url that is formatted with http:// instead of https:// they land on a different URL than what they would if they click on links on the website.

If a link from the home page the URL looks like this: https://www.example.com/rest_of_url

If a link is sent to the customer with http (http://www.example.com/rest_of_url) and they click on the link it will load: https://www.example.com/index.php?/rest_of_url

I have tried to remove index.php?/ from the URL string using .htaccess and the following code however this has not been effective:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php\?/ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php\?/ / [R=301,NE,L]
```

Any suggestions to stop people from landing on URLs with index.php?/ would be amazing

AS REQUEST THIS IS THE WHOLE htaccess FILE:
RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php\?/ [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php\?/ / [R=301,NE,L]
```

Comment: added above in the question

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

Comment: second case of RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. is not needed, you already sent all non www. requests to https ://www. This is just a comment, not an answer. L means last, so the first RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. already sent the user to both https and www, so the only thing you need to do after that is make sure that http ://www.yoursite.com gets sent to https ://www.yoursite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: Implemented and testing now